# how to looping to download excels from href (when the href was same for all files)

Tags: excel, vba

Targeting to download excels through href. However, Not able to download all excels with a loop (when the href links are looking same). what can be down in this case? once downloading those files how to save each excel in local C folder?

Here is the required HTML href links

```
<td class="tenderlink">
<a href='/Documents/ProcurementDisposal/20190419102042818.xls' 
         target="_blank">View</a></td>
```

Code:

```
Sub download()
 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As Object

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.nafed-india.com/Home/ProcDispoDetails"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With
    For Each ele In ie.document.querySelector("a[href^='/Documents/ProcurementDisposal']").Click
        Next ele
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of clicking each link, get the href attribute and pass that to `Workbooks.Open()`

Comment: If you want to add something, update your post, not my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving so far on my question. Will post separately as i have further questions on the code. Thanks a lot again for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub download()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim el As Object, els As Object

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.nafed-india.com/Home/ProcDispoDetails"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With

    'Note: querySelectorAll unless you only want one element
    Set els = ie.document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='/Documents/ProcurementDisposal']")
    For Each el In els
        Debug.Print el.href '<< pass this to Workbook.Open() then you can save the
                            '    workbook where you need
    Next


End Sub
```